# [UWP][C#] Como parar o anúncio de um serviço na rede local (unregisterService em android) com a API Windows.Networking.ServiceDiscovery.Dnssd

Tags: c#, windows, redes, uwp

O problema com que me deparo é que não estou a conseguir eliminar o um serviço dns-sd da rede local. Com o método RegisterServiço o serviço dns-sd é criado correctamente, mas não sei como fazer a eliminar esse mesmo serviço da rede local, ou seja o metodo UnregisterService não está a funcionar.
Agradecia ajuda nesse sentido.

```
  public async void RegisterService(WFIDnsServiceInfo dnsServiceInfo)
  {
     listener = getListener();
     await listener.BindServiceNameAsync("");
     dnssdServiceInstance = String.Format("{0}.{1}local", dnsServiceInfo.getServiceName(), dnsServiceInfo.getServiceType());
        listenServ = new DnssdServiceInstance(dnssdServiceInstance, null, 0);
        try
        {
            var result = await listenServ.RegisterStreamSocketListenerAsync(listener); 

            Log.LogMensage(this.GetType().Name, Log.Level.LevelInfo, "Serviço criado com sucesso!!!");

            //Serviço registado com sucesso
            getDelegate().onServiceRegistered(dnsServiceInfo);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Log.LogMensage(this.GetType().Name, Log.Level.LevelInfo, "Erro ao criar o serviço");

        }
    }
```

E o método para terminar o anuncio do serviço é o seguinte (não funciona ):

```
     public async void UnregisterService()
    {           
        Log.LogMensage(this.GetType().Name, Log.Level.LevelInfo, "UnregisterService!!!!");
        try
        {
            getListener().Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            Log.LogMensage(this.GetType().Name, Log.Level.LevelInfo, "Erro fechar serviço");

        }

    }
```

Comment: Bem vindo ao sopt. Pode editar a pergunta e deixar o problema mais claro? sinceramente eu não entendi nada.

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário, penso que assim está mais perceptível.